# ¿Como genero un PDF o un email a partir de un registro en un formulario en php?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pdf, email

ya tengo mi formulario para el registro de datos pero quisiera que al dar en el boton "registrar" ademas de que se mande la informacion a la BD se genere automaticamente un PDF con la informacion que se acaba de registrar?

Le he intentado de muchas maneras pero no me han funcionado, me pueden apoyar?

Comment: Utiliza algunas de las librerias para generar pdf en PHP actualmente yo utilizo FPDF, pero hay varios

Comment: ¿Podrias incluir el código con el que lo has intentado muchas veces e indicar en que parte crees tener el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Puedes enviar los datos ingresados a otra página donde se esté generando el PDF con librería.
2. Puedes hacer un index donde aparezcan todos los registros existentes y al dar clic en "Ver", envíe a la página donde se genera el PDF con librería.

Usa la librería [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) es muy fácil de usar y es muy compatible con php.

Con esta librería tu guardas la página en una variable y luego la renderizas, la página puede ser usada con PHP.

Acá un ejemplo.

```
<?php
include 'Controlador/conexion.php';
require_once 'includes\dompdf-master\autoload.inc.php';
require_once 'includes\ilovepdf-php-master\init.php';
ob_start(); // Desde aquí se empieza a almacenar la página
$ID_Evaluacion = $_POST["ID_Evaluacion"];//Acá recibimos la variable enviada desde un anterior formulario para realizar la búsqueda en la BD
$con = Conexion::Conectar();
$resultadop = $con->query("SELECT * FROM formulario_desempeno WHERE ID_Evaluacion = ".$ID_Evaluacion); // Puedes usar consultas MySQL
$resultadop->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ($resultado = $resultadop->fetch()) { ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Evaluacion</title>
    <img class="header" src="imagenes/header.png" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    <style type="text/css">
    html {
  margin: 30px;
}
    .header{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .p_info{
        width: 100%;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    h1, h2{
        background-color: #0199d9;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: black;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    h4{
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: black;
        padding: 2px;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    p{
        font-size: 12px;
        display: inline-block;

    }
    h1{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    h2{
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    table{
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    td{
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
    }
    th{
        background-color: #0199d9;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .calificacionevaluacion{
     background-color: #48baea;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    }
    .numeros_explicados{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .tdcalif{
        border-style: none;
    }
    .tdcal{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .seccion_sup{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        top:40px;
    }
    .seccion{
        display: inline-block;
    }

    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
        <h1>Datos del evaluado</h1>
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><label>Nombre Completo : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="NombreEvaluado" value="<?php echo $resultado["NombreEvaluado"]; ?>" ></td>
                <td><label>CC : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="CedulaEvaluado" value="<?php echo $resultado["CedulaEvaluado"]; ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Dependencia : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="DependenciaEvaluado" value="<?php echo $resultado["DependenciaEvaluado"]; ?>" ></td>
                <td><label>Fecha : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="FechaEvaluado" value="<?php echo $resultado["FechaEvaluado"]; ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Cargo : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="CargoEvaluado"  value="<?php echo $resultado["CargoEvaluado"]; ?>" ></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h1>Datos del evaluador</h1>
            <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><label>Nombre Completo : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="NombreEvaluador" value="<?php echo $resultado["NombreEvaluador"]; ?>" ></td>
                <td><label>CC : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="CedulaEvaluador" value="<?php echo $resultado["CedulaEvaluador"]; ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Dependencia : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="DependenciaEvaluador" value="<?php echo $resultado["DependenciaEvaluador"]; ?>" ></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Cargo : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="CargoEvaluador" value="<?php echo $resultado["CargoEvaluador"]; ?>" ></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <h1>Periodo de evaluación</h1>
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Periodo : </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $resultado["tipoperiodo"]; ?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Desde : </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="periododesde" value="<?php echo $resultado["periododesde"]; ?>" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Hasta : </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="periodohasta" value="<?php echo $resultado["periodohasta"]; ?>" ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p> La Evaluación del desempeño laboral, también incluye las competencias técnicas y conductuales requeridas para el desempeño del
            cargo y/o especialidad que ejerce en la organización.</p>
            <h1>1. Responsabilidades asignadas para el desempeño del cargo que desempeña:</h1>
                <p class="p_info" name="responsabilidades_asignadas" ><?php echo $resultado["responsabilidades_asignadas"]; ?></p>
                <div class="seccion_sup">
                <div class="seccion" style="width: 49.5%;">
            <h1 style="height: 120px;">2. Cumplimiento de las responsabilidades asignadas para desarrollo de actividades propias de su servicio y su colaboración con el objetivo de soluciones e inversiones BGA</h1>
                <p class="p_info" name="cumplimiento_responsabilidades" ><?php echo $resultado["cumplimiento_responsabilidades"]; ?></p>
                </div>

                 <div class="seccion" style="width: 49.5%;">
            <h1 style="height: 120px;">Aspectos que afectaron el cumplimiento de la responsabilidad por el profesional en la organización:</h1>
                <p class="p_info" name="afectan_cumplimiento"  ><?php echo $resultado["afectan_cumplimiento"]; ?></p>
                </div>
                </div>

                <table class="info_calificacion" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <th>   1   </th>
                        <td class="tdcalif"><p>Bajo</td>
                        <th>   2   </th>
                        <td class="tdcalif"><p>Bajo-Medio</td>
                        <th>   3   </th>
                        <td class="tdcalif"><p>Medio</td>
                        <th>   4   </th>
                        <td class="tdcalif"><p>Medio-Alto</td>
                        <th>   5   </th>
                        <td class="tdcalif"><p>Alto</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <table class="tablaevaluacion">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Conceptos de Evaluación</th>
                        <th>Evaluación por parte del Jefe</th>
                        <th>AutoEvaluación</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>A. Conocimiento del trabajo</th>
                        <th>Puntaje</th>
                        <th>Puntaje</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1. Domina los conocimientos técnicos relacionados con el cargo.</td>
                        <td class="tdcal"><?php echo $resultado["calificacion_1_jefe"]; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="tdcal"><?php echo $resultado["calificacion_1_auto"]; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2. Tiene capacidad para aplicar nuevos conocimientos.</td>
                        <td class="tdcal"><?php echo $resultado["calificacion_2_jefe"]; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="tdcal"><?php echo $resultado["calificacion_2_auto"]; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p class="p_info" name="Observaciones_finales"> Observaciones finales : <?php echo $resultado["Observaciones_finales"]; ?></p>
            <table align="center" style="width: 80%">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Firmas : </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Evaluado: </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;">__________________________________________</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Evaluador: </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;">__________________________________________</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
 </body>
 </html>

 <?php
 $html = ob_get_clean(); //Acá indicamos que es el final de la página y almacenamos en una variable.
}
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

$options = new Options();
$options->set('Times-Roman', 'Courier'); // Indicamos la fuente del PDF
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

$dompdf->loadHtml($html); //Acá se especifíca la variable donde almacenamos la página

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait'); //Indicamos el tamaño del PDF y la orientación

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream('EvaluacionDesempeño_'.$ID_Evaluacion.'.pdf', array("Attachment" => 0)); // Indicamos el nombre del PDF a generar. 
 ?>
```

> **AVISO:** El ejemplo realizado en la parte del query no está protegido contra Inyección SQL, lee este [POST](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php) para informarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero mi duda ahora es, este es individual verdad? no se debe de anexar en donde se encuentra el formulario para añadir los datos, por que quiero que ingrese los datos y al ingresarlos se guarden en la BD y se genere el pdf con los datos ingresados.
Es solo guardar en la variable y despues llamar la funcion? Gracias

Comment: Así es, puedes colocarlo en un archivo aparte al del formulario donde se ingresan los datos. Envías los datos del formulario al archivo para generar el PDF y armas tu página HTML de acuerdo a los datos.